# jQuery fadeTo() not fading due to appendTo() on complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some code seen below that creates a carousel effect for my website. The issue I'm having with it is that the original `fadeTo()` is not actually fading, rather waiting for the fade time to finish and then jumping to the next bit. (See Fiddle below).

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/o7h225sk/1/)

jQuery:

```
function next(ul) {
    ul.find("li:first-child").fadeTo(100, 0, function() {
        ul.find("li:first-child").appendTo(ul);
        ul.find("li:last-child").hide();
        ul.find("li:last-child").fadeTo(500, 0.4);
    });
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="carousel-container">
        <button class="prev"><</button>
        <div class="carousel">
            <ul>
                <li style="background-color: #333333">FIRST</li>
                <li style="background-color: #444444">SECOND</li>
                <li style="background-color: #555555">THIRD</li>
                <li style="background-color: #666666">FOURTH</li>
                <li style="background-color: #777777">FIFTH</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <button class="next">></button>
    </div>
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o7h225sk/1/) for CSS (There's quite a bit).

The issue is something to do with the second line of jQuery `ul.find("li:first-child").appendTo(ul);` as if I remove this then the fade works fine, however the carousel does not.

I'm open to other suggestions as to how I could do the carousel as well. This was just the first method that came into my head.

Answer (score 0):

You fade a element and also move it at the same time, try wrapping that append line that causes the problem in a settimeout of 100ms.